# ViewPager fragment content is blank at first time but works fine after first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application i am using recycler view to show images, click on every image should open a view pager and show current image, but the problem is that when i click any of image for first time it shows blank fragment, after this i click back key it shows recycler view again, now my app works fine,  click on any image shows fragment containing image perfectly. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code for recycler view

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
    CardView cv = holder.cardView;
//        Skiped un neccessery code from here

        cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            if (is_image_file){
                intent = new Intent(context, ImageOpener.class);
            }
            else {
                intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayer.class);
            }
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", position );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my code for ImageOpener.java class

```
public class ImageOpener extends AppCompatActivity {
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    private ArrayList<String> images_paths;
    private int size_of_pager, position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opener);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        images_paths = utils.load_images();
        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("POSITION");
        size_of_pager = images_paths.size();

        SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(size_of_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return size_of_pager;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos){
            return new OpenImageSlideFragment(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for OpenImageSlideFragment.java class

```
public class OpenImageSlideFragment extends Fragment {
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    ImageButton save_button, share_button;
    private ArrayList<String> images_path;
    private int position;
    String current_file;

    public OpenImageSlideFragment(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_image_slide, container, false);
        TouchImageView preview = (TouchImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.preview_image);
        images_path = utils.load_images();
        current_file = images_path.get(position);
        File imgFile = new File(current_file);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        Picasso.get().load(uri).into(preview);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Code for Utils.load_image()

```
public ArrayList<String> load_images(){
    System.out.println("in load image function");
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(""), "some/path/");
    File[] all_images = path.listFiles();

    ArrayList<String > imagePaths = new ArrayList<>();
//        for (int j=0; j<=2; j++)    //for just testing purpose
        for (int i = 0; i < all_images.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(all_images[i].getAbsolutePath());
            if (all_images[i].getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                imagePaths.add(all_images[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return  imagePaths;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using viewpager where you want to show multiple images then check this link it will help you

```
    https://youtu.be/DBOIQP3lI_w
```